# How to add some top offset in flex vertical centering when browser toolbar is active on small screens?

Tags: css

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

On computer and laptop this works great, elements are centered, but on phone, if toolbar of browser is in active mode, elements are pushed down for how much the toolbar takes.

I find that it is commong to use flex nowdays, so I used it to design simple login form.
On bigger screens I have side by side, image and login form, on smaller gadgets I have only login form visible.
On smaller screens, if browser toolbar appears it pushes login form (elements) down, so it does not really look like it is in center, which is not.

Is there a selector for active toolbar on phones and similar small gadgets, so we can add some top minus margin or something else to compensate this vertical centering?

Not a big problem at all, I just wonder if this can be done.

Comment: Please include all relevant code. We are programmers, not mind-readers.

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/@susiekim9/how-to-compensate-for-the-ios-viewport-unit-bug-46e78d54af0d) or [this one](https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/) might help you.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mre]